# Can anyone recommend the solution to solve ionic background issue in IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

The app is able to send the HTTP POST successfully as long as it's in the foreground, but as soon as it goes to the background, the HTTP POST appears to stop. This is only an issue for iOS.

I tried the cordova-plugin-background-mode plugin but i don't want the audio part. is there any working example code using angular ng.IHttpService.

```
 public GetEmployeeList(): ng.IPromise<Mobile.Models.Employee[]> {
            return this.$http.get("~/api/Employee/EmployeeList")
                .then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<Mobile.Models.Employee[]>): Mobile.Models.Employee[] => {
                    return response.data;
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just wanna keep your app alive when its in the background, surely the audio part is the easiest way.and to sove your particular issue, you need know how the "Background Model" works. https://upload-images.jianshu.io/upload_images/1501971-91e6c1164e13c3ee.png?imageMogr2/auto-orient/strip%7CimageView2/2/w/1000

Being curious why dont you wanna use the normal way to salve the problem since there are so many tracks to use with the background model.

Comment: Do you think background mode fetch will work with Angular IHTTPSerive?

Comment: The user clicks a button to post data to the API. The app then shows a "Please Wait" message while performs the Http Post. The user may put the app into the background at that time and sometimes the post will not complete due to the background.

it's text and an image file sometimes. The post does not necessarily take a long time to complete. 1 minute max, usually just a few seconds.

Comment: Seems like giving the app more time in the background to process the POST worked but then the app store didn't allow the background permission

Comment: not sure, you need check it out in Angular IHTTPSerive.

Comment: In IOS, we just use background model to keep our App alive in background, and there are few tricks to do that, such as, UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: nil), this will keep your app alive for a while, but not sure if it will salve your problem, you can try it when ever the user is in background.